# Memset appears to freeze my program C++ and other problems I don't see

Tags: c++, c, sockets, network-programming, ncurses

I have been making this server and I'm using **memset()** to clear a **struct addrinfo**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <vector>

#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define MAX_CONNECTIONS 10
#define MAX_SRSIZE 500

using namespace std;

struct bcpackage{
    string * message;
};
struct clientval{
    int fd;
};

vector<int> file_descriptors;
WINDOW * console, * input;

void * handleClient(void * arg);
void * broadcast(void * arg);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int myfd, * status;
    status = new int();
    struct addrinfo myaddrinfo, *res;

    /****************SETUP NCURSES UI******************/
    initscr();
    int y, x;
    getmaxyx(stdscr, y, x);
    console = subwin(stdscr,y - 1, x, 0, 0);
    input = subwin(stdscr,1,x,y-1,0);
    wrefresh(console);
    wprintw(input,">");
    /**************************************************/
    string port = "25544";
    wprintw(console,"port: %s\n", port.c_str());
    memset(&myaddrinfo, 0, sizeof(myaddrinfo));//Problem I think with this memset()
    myaddrinfo.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    myaddrinfo.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    myaddrinfo.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    wprintw(console,"Starting Server\n");
    int aistat = getaddrinfo(NULL, "25544", &myaddrinfo, &res);
    if( aistat == 0){
        wprintw(console,"Host Information Retrieved\n");
    }
    else{
        wprintw(console, "Error : %d\n%s\n", aistat, gai_strerror(aistat));
        getch();
        endwin();
        exit(1);
    }   //We now have our address now we create a socket
    myfd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype,res->ai_protocol);
    if(myfd==-1){
        wprintw(console, "Socket Creation Failed\n");
        wprintw(console,"Error: %d\n%s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        getch();
        endwin();
        exit(2);
    }
    //If all went well, we now have a socket for our server
    //we will now use the bind() function to bind our socket
    //to our program. I think that is what it does at least.
    *status = bind(myfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
    //wprintw(console, "Status: %d\n", *status);
    if((*status) < 0){
        wprintw(console, "Bind failed\n");
        wprintw(console,"Error: %d\n%s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        getch();
        endwin();
        exit(3);
    }
    else{
        wprintw(console, "Bind success\n");
    }
    //Now that we are bound, we need to listen on the socket
    *status = listen(myfd, MAX_CONNECTIONS);
    if(status>=0){
        wprintw(console, "Listening on socket\n");
    }
    else{
        wprintw(console, "Listen failed\n");
        wprintw(console,"Error: %d\n%s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        getch();
        endwin();
        exit(4);
    }

    //Everything is setup now we send the server into a loop that will pass
    //each client to a new pthread.
    while(true){
        int *clientfd = new int();
        pthread_t * cliPID = new pthread_t();
        struct sockaddr_in * cliaddr = new struct sockaddr_in();
        socklen_t *clilen = new socklen_t();
        *clilen = sizeof(*cliaddr);
        *clientfd = accept(myfd, (struct sockaddr *)cliaddr, clilen);
        file_descriptors.push_back(*clientfd);
        pthread_create(cliPID, NULL, handleClient, clientfd);
    }
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}

void * handleClient(void * arg){//Reads and writes to the functions
    int filedesc = *((int *)arg);
    string * rcvmsg = new string();
    while(!read(filedesc, rcvmsg, MAX_SRSIZE)<=0){
        if(rcvmsg->compare("")!=0){
            wprintw(console, "Client> %s\n", rcvmsg->c_str());
            broadcast(rcvmsg);
        }
        rcvmsg->clear();
    }
    delete rcvmsg;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void * broadcast(void * arg){
    string * message = (string *)arg;
    int num_fds = file_descriptors.size(); 
    for(int i = 0; i < num_fds; i++ ){
        write(file_descriptors.at(i), message, MAX_SRSIZE);
    }

}
```

Note that this written for linux and you need to add these linker commands when compiling, **-lpthread -lncurses**.
The big problem is that when I have the memset() line in, the program doesn't even run things before that line. It just sits there. When I comment that line out, it actually runs.
Another error is when I do take the memset() line out, **getaddrinfo()** gives a **ai_socktype not supported** error when I use **gai_strerror()** to find errors with **getaddrinfo().** Please help me. I'm really stuck and I don't see what's wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using `memset` correctly. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: You definitely need the `memset()` line or else the fields in `myaddrinfo` are not initialized properly. When `memset()` is there, you probably have a problem with your output.

Comment: The problem is with your UI, but I am not familiar with ncurses. The code works for me if I use `cout` instead of `wprintw`.

Comment: Are you missing a `wrefresh(console)` somewhere after `wprintw(console,"Host Information Retrieved\n");`?  Everything may be working fine, but perhaps the screen is not being updated?

Comment: Don't use `memset` for the initialization of a local variable. Initializers are part of C since the beginning of times, use them! Here it would be as simple as `struct addrinfo myaddrinfo = { 0 };` but this applies to most our your other variables, too.

Comment: Or even better just use the values that you want for initialization directly:
`struct addrinfo myaddrinfo = { .ai_family = AF_UNSPEC,  .ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM, .ai_flags =
AI_PASSIVE };`

Comment: BTW: The way you use `getaddrinfo()` is incomplete. If one of socket creation and connection fails, you should advance to `ai->ai_next` and retry with this, until the list is exhausted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's running just fine. What's happening is that when the program exits, your ncurses window is being destroyed and all its data is gone.

Add a single `getch()` before your `return 0` and it'll magically work.

Comment: I just put up all of my code and I do use getch() before I return 0 but it still does not seem to work.

Comment: Actually I think it may be me not refreshing the screen as msandiford says.